# IP Address issue on Iinux vm and vpn

Tags: linux

I think this is the right place to ask this question. 
so my current problem is that we have a virtual machine and a vpn. Our vm is a linux server and our vpn is a rpi.

Our vm is using a 10.x.x.x ip address. We connect that vm to a different vpn (using hamachi) that is also on a 10.x.x.x ip address.

My problem is the vpn on the vm is not connecting. When i try to ping it, im getting destination host unreachable. I then tried it with a windows vm and was able to connect to it.

So my question is, is there a different settings i should check on linux for it to connect? What is the reason why it wasn't connecting when i used a linux vm? Is the 10.x.x.x linux ip not compatible with the 10.x.x.x rpi ip or something? I just want to understand and try to fix the issue. Because we'd rather use a linux vm than a windows vm.

Comment: All IPs beginning with 10 are belonging to private range. So replacing your actual address with 'x' you only make your issue harder to determine and nothing else.

Comment: Please post the full ip address and netmask, your routing table and firewall rules.

Comment: @Mike Marseglia the vm's ip is 10.1.30.190 while the vpn's ip is 10.1.9.110 both have the subnet 255.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The basics of how a VPN works, IP addressing and routing are key.  Your VPN is probably made up of IPSec and a tunneling protocol, probably L2TP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol.

If you have a tunnel interface you would have entries in your routing table to match.  Linux can't route VPN traffic over the tunnel interface without entries in the routing table.

This ArchLinux wiki has very detailed instructions to configure an IPSec L2TP VPN from scratch.  If your VPN Server comes with a Linux client it will abstract away these manual steps.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup